# Is this a solution to the ODE - simple ODE question

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

We are given the first order linear differential equation:

$y'-2xy=1$

We have guessed a solution to the ODE: $y=e^{x^2}\int e^{-t^2}dt+e^{x^2}$

And we are asked, is this a valid solution to the ode

the problem I have with answering this, is that the limits of the integral were not specified. what is $\frac{\int e^{-t^2}dt}{dx}$? simple reasoning will say that the derivative of the integral is just the function itself, but inside the integral we dont have anything with $x$, it is a function of $t$, but $y$ is a function of only $x$...So how am I supposed to check this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that $\int e^{-t^2}dt$ should be read as $$\int_a^xe^{-t^2}dt$$ for any constant value $a$.

Comment: and the derivative of that with respect to $x$?